# Grant Mysql anonymous user access from other machines apart from localhost?

Tags: mysql

Mysql server allows access to anonymous user from localhost. I would like to extend this privelege to other machines as well... i.e. access to mysql_server running in machine A from mysql client from machine B using the anonymous user without any password.

I understand this is not practice and I want to do it only for certain dev purposes. Can anyone let me know how this is possible for mysql server.

The version I am using is - mysql_server 5.0.15

Answer (score 0):

To allow anonymous access to any host must use `%` wildcard:

```
GRANT ALL ON your_db.* TO ''@'%';
```

MySQL does not support wildcards in user names, but I think is better creating a `guest` username:

```
CREATE USER 'guest'@'%';
GRANT ALL ON your_db.* TO 'guest'@'%';
```